# QueryBuilder query array values

Tags: php, arrays, symfony, doctrine-orm

I have a query to get a username from the entity with date:

```php
return $this->createQueryBuilder('t')
    ->select('t.username')
    ->where('t.date = :date')
    ->andWhere('t.username = :username')
    ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ->setParameter('username', $username)
    ->getQuery()
;
```

However, when I want to find a username in the array, I use this:

`if (in_array($user_array, $username) != true) {`

I get this `$username` array:

```php
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'username' =>
    string(9) "username1"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'username' =>
    string(10) "username90"
  }
}
array(1) {
  [0] =>
  array(1) {
    'username' =>
    string(10) "username12"
  }
}
```

Is it even possible to search if the username is within the array? Do I need to adjust my QueryBuilder code or do I need to resort to another solution in Symfony?

Comment: Adjust your QueryBuilder is cleaner

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use the `in` function. As Example:

```
    public function getUser($arrays, $date)
    {
 $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder('t');
return $qb
    ->select('t.username')
    ->where('t.date = :date')
    ->andWhere($qb->expr()->in('t.username', $arrays) )
    ->setParameter('date', $date)
    ->getQuery()
;
}
```

More info [here](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/query-builder.html)

Hope this help

Comment: That is a good best practice. I now check if the username is not in the array in the function. Thank you for the referenced document.

Comment: Hi @Ricardo you are welcome! Of course, exist the expression `$qb->expr()->notIn`